# Get SQL results from same column multiple times

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns, ID And description. When ID = 1, the description represents the person's name. When ID = 2, the description represents the person's address. When ID is 3, the description represents the person's comments.

What query must I do to select all three types of description. I tried using cases but that won't work in my case. Union will work but I will be running my query three times. Is there a simpler and more effective way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? If you want all three, then just add a condition WHERE ID IN (1,2,3). But I think you want something more complicated, right?

Comment: Would it not be easier to just create 'Name', 'Address' and 'Comments' columns? Then you could simply restrict or not use full results?

Comment: Sounds like an [Entity Attribute Value pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) - this is not considered good design for relational databases. If this is your design, rethink it.

Comment: I agree but there are more than 3 ID. I just gave a small examples.

Comment: I want to get the person's name, address and comments all in one query (select all and insert into a temp table). The where in won't work since each row will have a different description. I want each row to have the three description.

Comment: Do you have any column common to all three ID values? If not I don't see how you can connect one name to another address...

Comment: @Nitrodbz what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you have some way to relate this data to a another table.  If so, then you can use something like this:

```
select t1.someId,
    max(case when t2.id = 1 then t2.description end) name,
    max(case when t2.id = 2 then t2.description end) address,
    max(case when t2.id = 3 then t2.description end) comments
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.someId = t2.someid
group by t1.someId
```

This will give you the unique, data for each record in a specific row. You can then insert this data into another table.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very bad approach you have there, but it can be solved by something like this:
(I added a personID to the table to be the primary key of it)

```
create table person(
personID int,
id int,
description varchar(40))

insert into person values (1,1, 'name')
insert into person values (1,2, 'adress')
insert into person values (1,3, 'comments')



SELECT p.personID, p.description, p2.description, p3.description
FROM person p JOIN person p2 ON p.personID=p2.personID and  p.id=1 and p2.id=2 JOIN person p3 ON p.personID=p3.personID AND p3.ID=3
```

Comment: yes I agree its not a good approach but this is what I have to work with. This is a valid approach but performance wise, it's not optimal.

Comment: I think its better than the "case". Take a look at the exec plan on a big data source

Comment: If you have several millions of rows in the table, would this perform better than the case solution?

Comment: its hard to say, but the thing is, your query, the way it is, is ging to produce 3 rows per person, is that what you want?

Comment: I didn't get three rows per person when I ran it. It gave me one row with 4 columns (the id and three description). See the query I posted if you want to refer to it.

Comment: yes you are right, I was using the wrong ID to test. Anyway, I would suggest you test both queries to find out whihc one is better performancewise

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. Thank you everyone who gave any feedback.

```
select table.ID,
max (case when id = 1 then description end) as size
max (case when id = 2 then description end) as address
max (case when id = 3 then description end) as comments
group by id
```

Comment: Can't mark my solution as the correct answer now. I can only do this after 2 days (stackoverflow programmed it to be this way). But I'll mark the other solution that matches my solution.